# Enable compression for SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure

Tags: backup, sql-server-2017, compression, azure

I am using SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure for multiple databases on my SQL Server 2017. I am trying to figure out how to enable compression on some of the databases. It seems from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-2017) that it should be possible as it recommends doing so if your backup size is going to exceed the max block blob size. However I cannot find any information on how to enable this.